# SearchBar not working while user is typing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewController with a search bar. The search works when the user taps the return button, but I cannot get it to update the UITable while the user is typing. I have implemented the "searchBardidBeginEditing" function, but it has not provided any search results. I would appreciate any help.

```
  var findgroups: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")



            if self.searchBar.text != "" {
                self.dataparse.removeAllObjects()
                findgroups.whereKey("GroupName", containsString: self.searchBar.text)
                findgroups.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (obs: [AnyObject]?, err: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if err == nil && obs != nil {

                        if let obs = obs as? [PFObject] {

                            for objex in obs {

                                self.dataparse.addObject(objex)

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })


            } else {



    findgroups.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        findgroups.orderByDescending("GroupName")
        if error == nil && objects != nil {



            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    self.dataparse.addObject(object)


                }

            }

        }



        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}

}




func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.loaddata()

}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()



}






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loaddata()
    searchBar.delegate = self


}


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.dataparse.removeAllObjects()
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    loaddata()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    loaddata()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you call the "searchBardidBeginEditing" function but this function only tells the delegate when the user STARTS searching with the UISearchBar. The searchBarSearchButtonClicked function also is just called when the user taps the bar. So you only call your update function two times and not every time the searchText changed.

To fix it take your data update function in the "searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)" function like this:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    loaddata()
}
```

You could also use the searchText and give it to loaddata() if you want because searchText is the same like self.searchBar.text

The following link will get you to UISearchBarDelegate Protocol Reference where you could see the sense of every function of the protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:textDidChange:

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question, some of the data obtained is in uppercase letters. The search bar matches only exact string, so if you have a group name called "Car", and you search "car", it does not find the name. How can I make it to consider both upper and lowercase text.

Comment: You can transform both strings to lowercase Strings and then compare them so there is no more upper letter. For that you can use the .lowercaseString attribute of every String. It will not change the original String :)